# Youtube analytics api giving 'Code:400 The query is not supported.' error

Tags: google-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using [googleapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package.

I want to get 'insightTrafficSourceDetail' from youtube analytics API.

Here is my code:

```
google.youtubeAnalytics('v2').reports.query({
    metrics: 'estimatedMinutesWatched,views',
    dimensions: 'insightTrafficSourceDetail',
    filter: 'video==[some_video_id];insightTrafficSourceType==YT_SEARCH',
    startDate: '2019-01-01',
    endDate: '2019-02-12',
    ids: 'channel==MINE',
    sort: '-estimatedMinutesWatched',
    maxResults: 25,
  });
```

Here is the response I am getting:

```
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { message:
        'The query is not supported. Check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v2/available_reports for a list of supported queries.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
```

Although in google docs, they have given the same request as sample request [Top 10 – External websites that generate the most traffic for a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#channel-traffic-source-reports)

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Could you find a fix?

Comment: In the above code, It should be 'filters' not 'filter'. When I replaced it, it started working perfectly. Make sure you are sending all params correctly and valid

Comment: Looks like we don't have the same problem. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
google.youtubeAnalytics('v2').reports.query({
    metrics: 'estimatedMinutesWatched,views',
    dimensions: 'insightTrafficSourceDetail',
    filter: 'video==[some_video_id];insightTrafficSourceType==YT_SEARCH',
    startDate: '2019-01-01',
    endDate: '2019-02-12',
    ids: 'channel==MINE',
    sort: '-estimatedMinutesWatched',
    maxResults: 25,
  });
```

In the above code, It should be 'filters' not 'filter'. When I replaced it, it started working perfectly.

`filters: 'video==[some_video_id];insightTrafficSourceType==YT_SEARCH',`